# gitignore: все кроме - не работает

Tags: git, gitignore

гит инициализирован в корне каталога.
Требуется отслеживание только двух директорий (со всем содержимым в них).

Пишу gitignor следующим образом:

```
/*
!/folder1/subfolder
!/folder2/
```

Но почему-то отслеживается только папка `folder2`. folder1/subfolder игнорируется. Пробовали разные варианты.. не работает. Если писать без вложенности,  т.е. так:

```
/*
!/folder1/
!/folder2/
```

То все работает. индексируются эти две директории. А как сделать, чтобы включить только эти две директории:

```
/folder1/subfolder
/folder2/
```

Comment: первые слэши убрать !folder1/... Вот подробнее https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files

Comment: Спасибо! Пробовал. Но не получается всеравно..

Вот пример:
/*
!bitrix/
bitrix/*
!bitrix/integration

Comment: Если речь о папке, то поставьте в конце строчки слэш.

Comment: man git-ignore пример в самом конце это как раз ваш случай. https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore